On the offset - Is it a correct expression?
I was told today that there is an expression like 'on the offset'. I have never heard of it, but since I am not a native speaker I wanted to check if this is a correct expression. I think this person might have confused it with 'on the opposite'. I looked it up but then I cannot find the definition for this phrase. Can anyone help me with it?
edit: the example I was given was like "On the offset, I like milk but it hurts my stomach" or something like this. Unfortunately I do not remember the exact sentence but what I know for sure is the opposite effects came after the cause of it. I am seriously considering that this was my teacher's mistake and she probably misheard "on the opposite", but could not really ask her back. :(

What was the context in which you heard this expression?

What do you think it means? There are Google hits with various contexts and meanings, but there are Google hits for many combinations of words. Just because a phrase exists doesn't mean you should use it.

I'm honestly surprised by how unhelpful Google is on this one, but it does turn up this, which is a pointer in the right direction. It seems there's debate over whether this use of "offset" is a mistake or not.

I hear on the off chance = in the remote case.

Context is very important. For example, I have seen the expression used in carpentry and in describing writing on artifacts ("on the offset between lip and bowl"), but offset is typically an adjective "on the offset portion" etc.

Perhaps you misremember "from the outset..."

Note that 'offset' does not mean 'setting off' in a journey sense.

OP Here, the example I was given was like "On the offset, I like milk but it hurts my stomach" or something like this. Unfortunately I do not remember the exact sentence but what I know for sure is the opposite effects came after the cause of it. I am seriously considering that this was my teacher's mistake and she probably misheard "on the opposite", but could not really ask her back. :(
